# How to refer to current node value in XSL for-each test?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let's say I have an XML doc like this:

```
<books>
    <book>1110</book>
    <book>1111</book>
    <book>1112</book>
    <book>1113</book>
</books>
```

I'm trying to setup a condition that tests the value of the current node in the `for-each`, but I'm doing something wrong:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/books/book">
    <xsl:if test=".[='1112']">
        Success
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: .[someBoolean] is syntactically invalid in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using `.` can, indeed, refer to the current (or "context") node, but not the way you're using it here.  In XPath, `.[foo]` is not valid syntax — you need to use `self::node()[foo]` instead.  Also, the `=` operator needs something to match against, in this case the `text()` selector to access the element's text contents:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/books/book">
    <xsl:if test="self::node()[text()='1112']">
        Success
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

As stated in the other answers, however, unless your `for-each` is performing other operations as well, you don't need to iterate at all and can use just `if` to accomplish the same task:

```
<xsl:if test="/books/book[. = 1112]">
    Success
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 13):

> I'm trying to setup a condition that
>   tests the value of the current node in
>   the for-each, but I'm doing something
>   wrong:

**The first thing that is incorrect is the syntax**:

```
   .[='1112']
```

**There are two things wrong here**:

1. **Within [ and ] there is no predicate**: the "=" operator needs two arguments but only one is provided.
2. **`.[x = y]` is still invalid syntax, although the predicate is OK**. This has to be specified as:

   self::node()[condition]

**The second thing** in the provided code **that can be improved** is the `<xsl:for-each>` instruction, which isn't necessary at all; A single XPath expression will be sufficient.

**To summarize**, one possible XPath expression that evaluates to the required boolean value is:

```
   /books/book[. = '1112']
```

**If it is really necessary that the condition be tested inside the `<xsl:for-each>`** instruction, then one correct XPath expression I would use is:

```
   . = '1112'
```

**The above** is a string comparison and **may not evaluate to `true()`** if there are spaces around. Therefore, **a numerical comparison may be better**:

```
  . = 1112
```

Answer (score 3):

While Ben has answered your question correctly, using for-each is most definitely the wrong general approach. After all this is XSLT. So you are probably more looking for something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="/books/book[text()='1112']">
  Success
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: True; I assumed the OP was just snipping out the relevant portion of a larger `for-each` block, but if that's the entirety of it, it would be far better to use this simple `if` instead.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT has a function specially for this problem.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
<xsl:for-each select="/books/book">
    <xsl:if test="current() = '1112'">
        Success
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:for-each>
```